# Get Dictionary<int, int[]> from query string ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dictionary, query-string

I have a parameter in my action method: `Dictionary<int, int[]> prop`, and I'm trying to set it through the query string. But when I use this:

```
/Action?prop[0].Key=123&prop[0].Value[0]=123
```

The dictionary parameter is not null but has no elements.

What am I doing wrong and how should I make it work?

Note: It's a page, so it's a HTTP GET Request which doesn't have body.

Comment: Seems like you'd be better off encoding it as JSON in the body instead of polluting the url.

Comment: Your code works fine and is correctly bound

Comment: @juharr It's a GET request. It does not have a body.

Comment: How is the controller supposed to bind "123" to an `int[]`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke Are you sure? 'cause It doesn't work when I check it out?

Comment: Absolutely (and I have tested it). If its not binding then its due to something you have not shown.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Holy shit! I just tested it again and it works! You were right, you can post it as an answer and then I accept it.

Comment: And answer that states you code is correct is a bit pointless :) - and I have already voted to close as non-reproducible. Suggest you delete it since its of not use to anyone else

Comment: @StephenMuecke StackOverflow wouldn't let me delete this 'cause it has an answer. :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your model, you may need a custom `ModelBinder`. See [Microsoft Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1) for more information how to build one.

A custom modelbinder lets you decide how your URL query parameter looks like. For example you could build one that would look like this:

```
/Action?dict=(1;1,2,3)(17;90,16,12345)(88;1,2,5,7,8,9,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
```

Apart from looking nicer and not spilling your implementation details, it also means you have to worry less about running out of space. Because most browsers don't support URLs longer than 4000 characters, so if your dictionary is larger, repeating the variable name each time is costly in terms of URL real estate.

Comment: OP code as shown works just fine - a custom model binder is not required

Answer (score 0):

Mark the parameter to MVC controller action with `[FromUri]` attribute as follows:

    `public HttpResponseMessage ActionName([FromUri] Dictionary<int, int[]> prop)
    {
        ...
    }`

In the request URI, append the dictionary as follows:

    `/actionName?prop[0].key=0&prop[0].value=11&prop[0].value=12&prop[1].key=1&prop[1].value=21&prop[1].value=22`

This results in the `prop` dictionary be filled as follows:
`
    prop : 
    {
        0 : [11, 12],
        1 : [21, 22]
    }

`